# MWAA 2.4.3 - AWSGlueJobOperator failed

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-2.x, mwaa

I am trying to update my AWS MWAA to Airflow 2.4.3
The DAGs I am using in 2.2.2 are breaking in the new 2.4.3 environment.

One such DAG is using AWSGlueJobOperator

```
glue_task = AWSGlueJobOperator(  
    task_id="TS-Learn-Source-To-Stage",  
    job_name='ts-learn-source-to-stage',
    region_name=Variable.get("region_name"),  
    iam_role_name='_AWSGlueDataBrewS3Access',  
    dag=dag)
```

I am using the same plugins that were used in MWAA 2.2.2 [here](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/795e88bb-17e2-498f-82d1-2104f4824168/en-US/workshop-2-2-2/setup/s3)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/airflow/plugins/awsairflowlib/operators/aws_glue_job_operator.py", line 93, in execute
glue_job = AwsGlueJobHook(job_name=self.job_name,
File "/usr/local/airflow/plugins/awsairflowlib/hooks/aws_glue_job_hook.py", line 71, in **init**
self.region_name = region_name
AttributeError: can't set attribute 'region_name'

I tried changing the script in the hook and the operator to set the region_name = "us-east-1" explicitly.

I am getting the same error.

[2023-03-08, 15:45:35 UTC] {{taskinstance.py:1851}} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/airflow/plugins/awsairflowlib/operators/aws_glue_job_operator.py", line 93, in execute
glue_job = AwsGlueJobHook(job_name=self.job_name,
File "/usr/local/airflow/plugins/awsairflowlib/hooks/aws_glue_job_hook.py", line 71, in **init**
self.region_name = "us-east-1"
AttributeError: can't set attribute 'region_name'

Can I please get help in understanding why it cannot set the attribute region_name when I have clearly passed region_name in the AWSGlueJobOperator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow 2.4.3 updated all the providers versions see the documentation [Apache Airflow v2 provider packages installed on Amazon MWAA environments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/connections-packages.html#connections-packages-table-243)

The Glue job operator in the apache-airflow-providers-amazon==6.0.0 is now called [GlueJobOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/operators/glue.html#submit-an-aws-glue-job)

Comment: Thank you! This Operator works. So, the AWSGlueJobOperator can no longer be used and I have to refactor all the affected DAgs?